# Automatic PlotRange based on Interpolation results

Tags: plotting, bugs, backslide

**Persisting through 11.3, fixed in Mathematica 12.0**

We generally use `PlotRange->All` to see all available points in a plot. But how do you use `PlotRange` when you want to run it with functions like the below without facing any data clippings.

This is best explained with a MWE:

```
data = {{1, 0.542399}, {2, 1.45729}, {3, 1.38588}, {4, 1.29452}, {5, 
  3.59352}, {6, 3.6808}, {7, 5.92152}, {8, 0.780593}, {9, 
  7.91613}, {10, 5.2081}};
```

Plot#1: general usage

```
ListLinePlot[data, 
 Epilog -> {Green, Line[data], PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[data]}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: 1]

Plot#2: Manually defined limits for x and y axis

```
ListLinePlot[data, 
 Epilog -> {Green, Line[data], PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[data]}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2, PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {0.1, 10}}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: 2]

Comment: a simpler MWE `ListLinePlot[data,  InterpolationOrder -> 2, PlotRange->All]`

Comment: Looks like a glitch introduced in v10 or later (the issue doesn't arise in version 9 -windows 10).

Comment: @kglr Damn! Looks like I have a knack to just find glitches. Or whatever I want happens to be a glitch.

Comment: Certainly a bug in `ListPlot`, please report it to the support.

Answer (score 2):

Clipping has nothing to do with the interpolation: `PlotRange` is defined based on the plotted data which in this case does not involve interpolated datapoints. I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature: the displayed spline is obviously not sampled to find its extrema, but this could be by design. Furthermore (not really relevant here, but important) if you include anything in the `Epilog` or `Prolog`, those are also not used when calculating `PlotRange`.

I suggest using an explicit `PlotRange`, but you can also incorporate the linear and splined functions in one plot:

```
data = {{1, 0.542399}, {2, 1.45729}, {3, 1.38588}, {4, 1.29452},
        {5, 3.59352}, {6, 3.6808}, {7, 5.92152}, {8, 0.780593},
        {9, 7.91613}, {10, 5.2081}};
Plot[{
  Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1][t],
  Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 2, Method -> "Spline"][t]
  }, {t, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> All, Epilog -> {Red, Point@data}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]